# PHP Errors on Making Local Copy of Server

Tags: php, path, echo

I have a site that I am trying to create a local copy of for test purposes (dusting off a past site).  I was able to correctly get the db out and most of the site works great.  However, I have places where things aren't loading correctly and are just giving me errors or messages in curly braces.

For example, a td class' name is being replaces with {BOX_HEADER} or on another page instead of a flash loading it just displays {PAGE} in the spot where the flash should be.  Has anyone seen errors like this before?

I was thinking it could be PATH/echo errors but I was seeing if anyone had experienced problems like this before.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a CMS or an app with Smarty templates?
Maybe osCommerce? Please give some more information about what you are doing so people have something to go on.

Answer (score 1):

There's a very good chance that you have some hard coded paths (and perhaps URL's also). When you copied the site, your docroot / home directory changed. So, if you had /home/elmer/public_html/site , you'll likely need to change that.

Look for an error_log file in all sub folders (especially where your template parser lives) and you should be able to root it out rather quickly. If all but DB configuration is stored in the DB, that's the first place to check.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like your templating solution is not working correctly. On the surface this is hard to diagnose because these are not typical php errors. You probably are going to have to do a little digging or provide some more information like which templating engine you're using.